# How to check for the distance from a ledge? Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I want an enemy in my game to turn around before reaching a ledge. This is the code I currently use.

```
public LayerMask groundLayer;
public Collider2D solidCollider;
public bool OnGround => Physics2D.Raycast(solidCollider.bounds.center,
                                Vector2.down, 
                                solidCollider.bounds.extents.y + 0.02,
                                groundLayer);
public bool _lookingLeft;

public bool HandleLedgeCheck(float distanceFromLedge = 0.5f)
{
        if (OnGround)
        {
            float pointX = _lookingLeft ? 
                    solidCollider.bounds.center.x 
                        - solidCollider.bounds.size.x * 0.5f 
                        - distanceFromLedge : 
                    solidCollider.bounds.center.x 
                        + solidCollider.bounds.size.x * 0.5f 
                        + distanceFromLedge;
            return !Physics2D.OverlapCircle(
                    new Vector2(pointX, 
                        solidCollider.bounds.center.y 
                            - solidCollider.bounds.size.y 
                            - 0.2f), 
                    0.5f, groundLayer);
        }
        else
        {
            return false;
        }

}
```

It works but it has to run every Update. Is there a way to calculate the distance from the ledge only on start and when the enemy turns around? Will it work with TileMaps using CompositeCollider2D?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if i have understood very well, but i think that you can make a variable outside the update function that contains the position of the ledge where he is going and then calculate the distance every update, if he is close you just have to change direction and set the variable to the oder ledge position
I don't speak english very well so i hope you understood everything!